# How can byte strings be stored well? - Not JSON Serializable -

Tags: python, json, encoding

For a project, I'm collecting several infrared commands using a sensor with an easy [python module](https://github.com/artgrouplimited/motedem-sdk-python).

**I receive byte strings like these:**

```
commando1= b'7g4770CQfwCTVT9bQDAzVEBMagGRMDhUOwBjATsAXVBAAJt17QMMV3AAH6qJABawTVJ0UiIRETERQRIkIlRFERZ4eXkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA5'
commando2= b'\x04O\xdb\x07L\x9c\xd5\x1f\xccT=[\x9103T\x91Lj\x01\xdd0\x97y\xcc\x08W\x0b\x91\x00\xf3\xac\x01""pt\x11\x11]B!cmo\x12pd_u\x97u\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x96'
commando3= b"\xdb\x06}\xad5P\x13\x835L\xf3N50\xd3T<L'\x02\x810{S5\x00`\x015\x00xP5\x00\xecZ\x87\x00\x04Ne\x00\x9b\x9cO\x02\x81\x97\xac\xa0R\xa0\x08\x01\x013E`\x07\x00p\x08\x01\x013E`\x07\x00p\x08\x01\x013E`\x07\x00p\x08\x88"
commando4= b'\x924"<"\x0b\x10\x14\x00L\xdfN\xdf0\x00R\x00LJR\\@\x10c\x01\x01M\x01\x00\x111O\x01 \x03Pb\x01\x10L0\x00RLN\x00NRL0R0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbb'
```

**And want to store them in JSON to get some order in there:**

> TypeError: b'7g4770CQfwCTVT9bQDAzVEBMagGRMDhUOwBjATsAXVBAAJt17QMMV3AAH6qJABawTVJ0UiIRETERQRIkIlRFERZ4eXkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA5' is not JSON serializable

I've tried encoding/decoding this series of characters, which doesn't work. I don't think it is the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: convert it `hex` and store, and the `load` and `decode` ?

Comment: Can you share how did you encode/decode the bytes?

Comment: @windstorm commando.decode(), with ascii, utf8 and also base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytes are not JSON-serializable, but since your input looks to be all within ASCII range, you can simply decode it into a string with the `ascii` encoding so that it can be JSON-serialized:

```
commando.decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Seems like not all of the data I'm receiving is ascii decodable. I've added more examples to show the diversity. Is there an approach to figure out the encoding?

Comment: @kilian579: Instead of ASCII, you can use the `latin-1` codec, which is a 1-to-1 codec that can convert any random string of bytes to a `str` of Unicode ordinals from 0 to 255 inclusive (they may not be printable, but they should be JSON encodeable). Alternatively, modern Python offers the `.hex()` method to convert `bytes` to a `str` of hex digits, and the `bytes.fromhex` alternate constructor to convert back; would use two characters per byte, but it would be consistent and human readable (where a `latin-1` decode would use variable length due to escapes or might produce unprintable output).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I call that "Base256". It works but people can get very confused by what looks like text with the character encoding from the surrounding context but requires an additional decoding step to use properly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger can't get `fromhex` to work. Would you have an easy example?

Comment: @kilian579: `bytes.fromhex('abcd')` produces `b'\xab\xcd'`. It's an alternate constructor, so you call it on the *type*, not an *instance* like you would with normal methods, as a different way to make a `bytes` object. (It can be called on a `bytes` instance too, but it doesn't use anything from the instance, so it's usually clearer to call it on the class).